# Uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Singleton

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to define a singleton ActiveRecord model. I do this:

```
class Universe < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord::Singleton

end
```

But I receive an error: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Singleton.
I assume, I missed *require "something"*. What should I require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched through the [Rails documentation for 3.03](http://api.rubyonrails.org/) and I don't see any reference to ActiveRecord::Singleton. Are you absolutely sure this is a valid name?

I did find a reference to this [library](http://actsassingleton.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Singleton.html) that appears to add this functionality though. Are you using this library?

Comment: I believe, I using this library, but I didn't install plugin. I thought, this is rails functionality, but it didn't. Does this mean, rails doesn't have core functionality for singleton model?

Comment: I had the same problem as yukas. This documentation, https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/acts_as_singleton/0.0.5/ActiveRecord/Singleton seems to imply there is a gem that does this. In the end I just ended up using the ruby Singleton pattern, using ```include Singleton```.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are actually looking for ActiveRecord::Singleton? There is a Singleton-Module in the rails-standard-library:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html

maybe this is what you are looking for?!